# Detect when passing anchor point in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, anchor

how would i detect when scrolling pass an anchor point in jquery? There are more then one on the same page.

```
<a href="#test"></a>

<div id="test" name="test">Test Message here</div>

<div id="test1" name="test1">Test Message here</div>

<div id="test2" name="test2">Test Message here</div>

<div id="test3" name="test3">Test Message here</div>

 ect...
```

Thanks

Comment: I'm sure you have tried something, no?

Comment: yes i have but i can only detect one anchor point

Comment: Are you trying to detect scrolling past anchors, or all those divs ?

Comment: detect scrolling past anchors

Answer (score 12, accepted):

something like :

```
var anchor_offset = $('a[href="#test"]').offset().top;

$(window).on('scroll', function() {
    if ( $(window).scrollTop() > anchor_offset ) 
         $('#test').show();
});
```

Comment: Sorry I for to add there are multiple points on the same page

Answer (score 3):

http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/

```
$('h2').waypoint(function(direction) {

 //alert('Top of thing hit top of viewport.');

});
```

Comment: thanks for the 'waypoint' term, i was looking for something like this in reactjs and found react-waypoint ;)